# Android ICS: how to choose a self-installed user Certificate from KeyStore properly

Tags: android, types, keystore

we are developping a client for android.  at first the user has to decide which Certificate gets used for the connection (ikev2). is there a propper way to do this?

all i found is a loop over all installed certificates, if the typed alias (through user input==very bad) is matching the certificate alias "CN=foobar CA,O=foobar,C=CH" we take it, but its taking ages as you can imagine and the fact that the user has to type in the alias is not applicable...

```
public X509Certificate getCACert(String caName){
    ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore");
    Enumeration<?> aliases = ks.aliases();
    while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
        String alias = (String) aliases.nextElement();
        cert = null;
        try {
            cert = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (cert.getSubjectDN().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(caName)) {
            break;
        }
    }
return cert;
}
```

is there maybe a prebuild callback for selecting user certs, maybe a type for keystore.getInstance("type4userCA") which returns only the user CA's without the preinstalled CA's or has anybody an idea how to filter it another way?

i saw that the android-vpn setting is able of displaying only the userCA's in a spinner, but they are using the keystore.saw() method which i cant use on my java.security.keystore...

thx

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? To connect to a VPN, etc. you need to select the user's private key, not sure whey you are going through the CA certs. You can display the selection dialog with something like this, and your callback will receive the selected alias:

```
public class KeystoreTest extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
     KeyChainAliasCallback {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias(this, this, 
           new String[] { "RSA" }, null, null, -1, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void alias(final String alias) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Log.d(TAG, "selected alias: " + alias);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, we authenticate the connection with a server cert. i also found your code, and we are using it to install the cert, but if the user has two different CA's he has to use, how can i get a list of all user certs where he can choose which one he want... saving all imported alias and presenting them is ok, but i think there has to be sth better where he can also see some details an so on...

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are doing, but it is highly unlikely that the user has many client certificates (with private keys) installed. The above will show only those, there shouldn't be more than a few. The system is built this way on purpose: access to private keys is managed by the system, including the selection UI to make it harder to trick users into using compromised keys, etc. There is no SDK visible API for listing private keys AFAIK. (The code is there on the system level, of course).

Comment: ok thx a lot, its for the authentication of a vpn server with a cert and psk... thats why we dont really need the private key... i just need the certificate object which i can pass to the ikev2 process. so if there is a possibility of generating a selection UI which shows only the user certificates, without all the preinstalled CA's just let me know. thx a lot again

Comment: If you know the fingerprints (SHA-1, etc. hashes) of the certificates you are installing, you can filter the list and only show those. Other than that, there is no API, the system doesn't really make a distinction between user- and system certificates (that's a feature).